# iterate through javascript objects issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am i getting the wrong result iterating through the javascript(new to JS):

```
var data = "data":{
   "unknown_name":{
             "0":{
                  "price":"23432",
                  "name":"one"
              },
              "1":{
                  "price":"23432",
                  "name":"two"
              }

    }

}
```

my attempt:

```
var name = Object.keys(data.data)[0]
var data_data = data.data[name]
Object.keys(data_data).forEach(function(key) {

           console.log(key, obj[key]);
});
```

I am trying to print price and value but its not working.

Comment: your object syntax is wrong.
either remove "data":{....
or wrap it in { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var data = {
      "data":{
        "unknown_name":{
                 "0":{
                      "price":"23432",
                      "name":"one"
                  },
                  "1":{
                      "price":"23432",
                      "name":"two"
                  }
    
        }
      }
    }
    for(var name in data.data){
      var data_data = data.data[name];
      for(var key in data_data){
        console.log(data_data[key].name+":"+data_data[key].price);
      }
    }
```